# Can I use an USB Ethernet adapter to connect Sony Ericsson Xperia Active to a wired Ethernet LAN?

Tags: networking, usb-host-mode, usb-peripherals, sony-xperia-active

Due to my profession I have to connect to wired-only LAN-attached devices (like managed switches, routers set-top-boxes, etc.) frequently to access their configuration interfaces via Telnet/SSH/HTTP. I am totally tired of carrying a bag with a laptop with me wherever I go.

Now I am planning to buy an Android smartphone and feel like I'd like it to be Sony Ericsson Xperia Active which is pretty tough (I need it very much as my phones fall from my hands/table/pocket hundreds times a year), reasonably robust and stylish.

It would simplify my life significantly if I could connect it to wired Ethernet networks.

Is this possible?

I don't mind using a hack or a custom firmware like Cyanogen Mod. I've already got a USB NIC based on ASIX AX88772 chip (which is detected by Ubuntu out of the box and, AFAIK, is also compatible with XBox, PS3 and Apple Macs).

Comment: [How to make Ethernet work on Android over OTG?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225741/218526)

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer but a good alternative. Buy this inexpensive [wifi powerbank](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0093IPJKQ).

This is practically a very portable wifi router. I bought and use one and so far its great. Can also be an inexpensive Mifi device using a 3G dongle, and a backup battery for your phone.

Comment: Nice thing. Thank you. I feel like I am going to buy it. The question remains open though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of these things :

1) By an usb to ethernet cable.

I dont know about Sony Xperia Active but you can use the Nexus 7 or Samsung S4 and a usb to ethernet cable (like rj45) plus an otg cable. For method view the following [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvu33kshlSY).

2) By Usb internet or pass through.

On some android devices like mine (htc 816g) there is an Usb internet option in settings which helps you to use the computer's internet (Only windows), on your phone.
For method view following [video](https://www.youtube.com/attribution_link?a=JLUnGetHbpI&u=%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DYRoH8aiSzWk%26feature%3Dshare).

v=gcFDGkTd83Y&feature=iv&src_vid=zEpyImojbsU&annotation_id=annotation_1409430545

Comment: Your answer would become unhelpful the moment the said links expires. Please consider adding relevant info here to make the answer self-sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

To my experience on sony xperia smartphones internet through ethernet adapter works flawlessly on devices like z, z2 z3 z ultra m5 only until android lollipop 5.0.2 afterwards there seems a change in software which disables this function ality fortunately ut is easily possible to downgrsde. Newer models like z5 may have lost this functionality atleast for lollipop and there you may not be able to downgrade depending on the original firmware

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full list of compatible devices: [What Xperia devices support USB Host or USB OTG?](https://support.sonymobile.com/gb/xperiaxa/faq/apps-&-settings/02310188027b445c5013d73c192e8007d3c/)

I think that OTG Ethernet adapters will be unsupported for a few years because of some Android security issues which may require some extra work, and because they are "less" important features (not everyone who owns an Android device needs an Ethernet adapter). Some examples of exploited vulnerabilities are shown here:

[MTPwn](https://github.com/smeso/MTPwn)

[OATmeal on the Universal Cereal Bus: Exploiting Android phones over USB](https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.com/2018/09/oatmeal-on-universal-cereal-bus.html)